# Continuous functions which I must lift my pencil to draw

Tags: definition, continuity

Am I correct in thinking that the following three functions are continuous?

$$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{x+2}$$

$$g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+2}$$

[image]

Edit: because of my creativity with the graph, I'm going to have to share its definition for clarity: $$h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}
&4.2 &1\leq x<3.75\\
0.3x+4 & 3.75<x\leq 7 \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Continuous where? None of those functions are continuous on $\Bbb R$. If you restrict the domain as you said to $\Bbb\setminus\{-2\}$ then they are continuous on their domain, but that isn't very meaningful since you just cut out the discontinuous part.

Comment: None are continuous, the first has a removable discontinuity and the second and third have nonremovable discontinuities

Comment: @LanierFreeman Please, show a point where the first function is defined and doesn't satisfy the definition of continuity. The same for the other two functions.

Comment: Yes these functions are continuous. However it is no surprise that you cannot draw the functions without lifting your pen, because the domain itself is disconnected: you would not be able to get from one "piece" of the domain to another no matter what the function was.

Comment: @egreg Well you're assuming were only discussing continuity within the confines of the functions' respective domains

Comment: @LanierFreeman How can you discuss continuity of a function where it is *not* defined?

Comment: @egreg Not being defined at a point automatically prevents a function from being continuous at said point because even if the limit is the same from both sides the function isn't defined and thus can't meet this requirement for continuity

Comment: @LanierFreeman the first two functions are not continuous at $x=-2$, but neither are they discontinuous there.

Comment: @egreg I suppose I incorrectly assumed continuity was dichotomous. So you're trying to say that the issue of continuity of a function only extends to its domain?

Comment: @LanierFreeman Yes, according to the definitions in all modern analysis books I know.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the clarification, I've yet to take analysis

Comment: Consider whether or not $h(x)$ is continuous for $x<1$.

Comment: By the way, your graph is statistically misleading.  ;)

Comment: @Lanier: "the issue of continuity of a function only extends to its domain?" It's simple. Is $f(x) = x^2$ continuous at $x=\text{potato}$?

Answer (score 2):

Those are continuous functions, and that means they are continuous on their domains.  However, their domains have limit points to which those functions cannot be extended continuously.

Comment: I thought that if a function had a discontinuity, it was by definition not continuous? The first two functions are not continuous at $x=-2$ and the third is not continuous at $x=3.75$ (and it approaches two different values depending on direction).

Comment: And the idea that continuity means “can be drawn without lifting the pen” is wrong. A simple example is $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @user51819 : Indeed, if a function has a discontinuity, then it is not continuous. But what is a discontinuity.  By the definition I'm following above, a discontinuity would occur at any point in the domain at which the value differs from the limit.  But there are no such points in the domain. As I said, there are limit points of the domain to which the functions cannot be extended continuously. $\qquad$

Comment: Maybe my definitions are wrong. My understanding was that a limit says nothing about the actual value AT that limit. For instance, let $y=0$ at $x=0$ but $y=1+x$ otherwise, the limit at $x=0$ would still be $1$, but we'd say it's not continuous because you can't trace through the entire function without lifting up the pen.

Comment: And in the third example the limit as $x$ approaches $3.75$ from the left is $4.25$ or so whereas if you approach $x=3.75$ from the right, the limit is $5.25$. Does that not mean it's discontinuous?

Comment: @user51819 Think more simply as the domain is discontinuous, not the function itself.

Comment: @SimpleArt What do you mean? Example?

Comment: @user51819 $f(x)=x$ for all $x\ne0$, so the function is continuous everywhere it is defined, but its domain is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @user51819 : The fact that those two one-sided limits differ does mean that you cannot extend the function to a function that is continuous on the larger domain, which includes that one extra point. $\qquad$

Comment: @egreg Regarding $f(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$, this depends on what you mean by "can be drawn". This function $f$ cannot be drawn without lifting a pen because it cannot be drawn at all (in a sense): It has infinite length on $x\in (-1,1)$. But in this sense, you could argue that $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ cannot be drawn either, because the set $\mathbb{R}$ is not finite. I don't think this is a useful way of thinking about "can be drawn".

Comment: @MrPink With a fundamental difference. You can draw any arc (segment) of it, which is not true for $x\sin(1/x)$. Anyway, this notion of continuity is essentially the same as arc-connectedness and is quite hard to generalize to spaces of higher dimension.

Comment: @egreg The function $f$ defined above is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and you say that there is at least one segment of $f$ which cannot be drawn. But then you say that this notion of continuity is the same as arc-connectedness... I'm quite consfused.

Comment: @MrPink I use *continuous* in the modern sense. The function shows the weakness of the concept based on “drawing”.

Comment: @egreg I agree. But why did you mention higher-dimensional spaces?

Comment: @MrPink Because that's an example where the definition by “drawing” does not generalize, at least easily, which instead is true for the current definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all three are continuous functions.

The definition of continuity at a point is based on the fact that the function has a value at that point (if a function is continuous at $x = a$, then $f(a)$ has a value in the expression $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$). However, it does not make sense to consider points at which a function is not defined. If we were asked to prove that the function is ‘discontinuous’ at a point, we would need to show that the condition for continuity at that point is false. And the negation of the condition for continuity ($\exists\epsilon >0\ \forall \delta>0,\ |x-a|<\delta \text{ and } |f(x)-f(a)|\geq\epsilon$) would not make sense at a point where the function value is not defined. In this way, I think that high school mathematics may often overlook this nuance in the definition of continuity. One usually thinks of continuity in a setting where a function is mapped from a set of real numbers, but let’s quickly extend this idea to a more abstract setting. If $X$ is a metric space, and $b$ is not an element of $X$, then is a function $f:X\to X$, that is otherwise continuous on $X$, discontinuous simply because it is not defined at $b$? One can clearly see the absurdity in this, and in the same way, we should only consider the subset of the real numbers that is the domain of a function when asking questions about continuity. The domains of the first two functions $f$ and $g$ above are $\mathbb R \setminus \{-2\}$.

For a textbook reference, see [this page from M. Searcóid's textbook *Metric Spaces*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwQuk.jpg).